Iterate element inside html div element
I am not familiar with javascript and facing this weird situation.
I am using javascript to iterate over div element and retrieve href values from all <a> element inside, the purpose is to handle click on <a> element by JavaScript instead of default by HTML.
The iteration works but all links target replaced to the last <a> href values.


$(document).ready(function() {
  //NavMenu();
  //NavActive();
  NavClick();
  console.log('tes');
});

function NavClick() {
  var nav_item = document.getElementById('nav-menu').querySelectorAll('div')
  for (let i = 0; i < nav_item.length; i++) {
    item = nav_item[i].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')
    nav_item[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: item,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          $('title').html(data.title)
          window.history.replaceState({}, '', item)
          $('#content').html(data.data)
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-12 justify-content-end" id="nav-menu">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/" class="px-1">
            Short
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/myurl/' %}" class="px-1">
            My URL
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/group/" class="px-1">
            My Collection
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/group/create/" class="px-1">
            New Collection
        </a>
  </div>
</div>



What I expecting is my code will add event listener to each  element and retrieve the "href" value so I can send request to server with the url.
eg. when I click this link, javascripts will send request to 127.0.0.1 but what i get is request send to 127.0.0.1/group/create/.
<div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/" class="px-1">
        Short
    </a>
</div>

is my logics wrong or I miss something on my codes?

why do you use document.getElementById('nav-menu').querySelectorAll('div') and not document.querySelectorAll('#nav-menu div')? Dont mix jQuery and JavaScript! <a>nchors are for redirecting to another webpage not to call APIs. So you might want to explain what you actually intend to do. Possible XY issue.

@tacoshy :the purpose is to handle click on  element by JavaScript instead of default by HTML. why? because I want to send API request to server when user click the link. I may not familiar with javascript but I know what  in html is. but thanks

@DarkBee will it possible to work? I will list in my option, thanks.

You don't use anchors do trigger an API call. You use a button or an input type submit for it. An anchor should only be used if you want to redirect to another resource such as leading to another website! That is why it it is an XY issue. If you would use the correct element, you would not need to find a solution to prevent the default behavior of an anchor that you don't want in the first place.

@tacoshy ok then

Since you don't want the actual anchor behavior and direct it to another resource, you should not use an anchor. 
As you said that you want to make an API call, you should use a button as a semantic "script trigger element". The link/url you placed wrongly inside a hrefcan be placed within a data attribute. In the code example, I gave it the name link (data-link).
Add the event listener directly to the button and make your element selector shorter and more readable by using document.querySelectorAll('#nav-menu button'). Then iterate through the Node List (what querySelectorAll returns) and add the event listener directly to each element. You can also look into event delegation if you want to improve your JS skills further.
You can read out the URL then by using this.dataset.link


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const NAV_ITEMS = document.querySelectorAll('#nav-menu button');
  NAV_ITEMS.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const LINK = this.dataset.link;
      console.log(LINK);
    })
  })
});
<div class="row col-12 justify-content-end" id="nav-menu">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button data-link="/" class="px-1">Short</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button data-link="/myurl/' %}" class="px-1">My URL</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button data-link="/group/" class="px-1">My Collection</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button data-link="/group/create/" class="px-1">New Collection</button>
  </div>
</div>




I am listing your answer, I already tried your previous suggestion and replace the anchor tag with button for now (maybe I will use something different if possible). is it a good implementation using button for navigation menu? I am not very good at UI/UX design.

HTML-wise you have to think about what you trying to achieve and what the semantical tags are for that. If it comes down to styling, then this is a CSS issue. But to answer the question for you, the question misses to much context in the form of details. What is it that you're programming (website, app, SPA...), how do you want to navigate and where? Why do you need to make an API call...

I am using Django and Django Templates, my goals is to make those navigation worked without reloading the whole page. is there any article or documentation for those data-link? UI is not a big problem, I can use AI for generate the design. I just need this navigation link to send request to my server so I can changes some parts of my html. I want to navigate user to other page without full reload.

That means, that you want to write a SPA (Single Page Application). Then anchors are indeed most likely not the right approach. You should not search for data-link but for data attribute on MDN WebDocs

owh okay, thanks for your answer. i learned a lot of new things today

All you need to do is set up a click listener, check if it's an a tag that's being clicked, and use preventDefault() to override the navigation.
No loop required. No JQuery required.


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  function hijackLink(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName == 'A') {
      console.log(event.target.href);
      event.preventDefault();    
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', hijackLink);
  // EDIT, due to comment
  // document.getElementById('nav-menu').addEventListener('click', hijackLink)
});
<div class="row col-12 justify-content-end" id="nav-menu">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/" class="px-1">
            Short
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/myurl/' %}" class="px-1">
            My URL
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/group/" class="px-1">
            My Collection
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <a href="/group/create/" class="px-1">
            New Collection
        </a>
  </div>
</div>




this will affecting all  element in the document doesn't it?

Certainly, but you don't need to add the click listener to the whole document, but instead to document.getElementById('nav-menu').

function NavClick(){
    const homeurl = 'http://127.0.0.1';
    var nav_item = document.getElementById('nav-menu').querySelectorAll('div')
    for (let i=0; i<nav_item.length; i++){
        item = nav_item[i].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href')
        nav_item[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: homeurl + item,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $('title').html(data.title)
                    window.history.replaceState({}, '', item)
                    $('#content').html(data.data)
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

Hope it will help you. Try to define the homeurl as constant variable.
By default if you click the link("/") from 127.0.0.1/group/create page, by default it will go to 127.0.0.1/group/create link. So, always use as const variable for  homepage url is safe option

This is not the issue OP is experiencing

it fixed now, following answer by Bardia Mazaheri. but thanks for your answer, more answer means more option to try

No it doesn't - this doesn't even address the problem OP is experiencing
